# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x→t}\frac1{x-t}{(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\mathrm e^x)-e^t)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$t=\lim_{x→t}\frac{\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^x\right)-e^t\right)}{x-t}$ , find t
how can we get the solution/s for the equation?
Also for what value of t would there be no solution?
I used the chain rule to simplify $\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^x\right)$ by
$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^x\right)$=$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^x\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dx}\right)$=$\frac{e^xdx}{dt}$
 Then I tried  using the L-hopital's rule, but couldnt reach anywhere.....
For the next part of the question I thought that the equation may not have a solution for t=e, while plotting the graphs, which turned out  to differ in the answer and (and I think also it will in the number of solutions, as the) for varying values of t, still unable to understand how to find out the answer in terms of t.
I tried to plot the following on graph, at t=e which turned out to be--[image: like this]
For other values of t it turned out to be---[image: like this][image: and like this]
Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Finding the limit, ie. t

Comment: Where is this coming from ?

Comment: Let me explain more clearly about the question------ 
The question is finding t and finding such a value/ values/ set of values of t that do not satisfy the equation, or simply finding the value for which graph of the limit(in orange) doesn't meet with that of x=t (in blue).

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, but  I didn't get you

Comment: @Aatmaj: you don't known where this question is coming from ???

Comment: @Aatmaj: you did not answer.

Comment: If you want the source, then it is from a book on mathematics, which is in the process of publishing. the book doesn't state the answer to this particular though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is independent of $t$ and $\dfrac{d}{dt}e^x=0$. The limit does not exist.

Comment: x is a variable, t is a variable, x tends towards t. does that mean x is independent of t?

Comment: @Aatmaj: please tell me the functional relation between $x$ and $t$.

Comment: x tends towards t, or x=t

Comment: @Aatmaj: in a limit computation, you never evaluate the function at the limit point. So the *only thing* which is sure is $x\ne t$.

Comment: absolutely, I agree x≠t, but x tends towards t. doesn't that make x dependent upon t?

Comment: If x would have been independent of t, x could have been equal to t. x approaches towards t, change in value of t changes the value x tends to.................

Comment: @Aatmaj: what is the functional relation between $x$ and $t$ ?

Comment: x=t+c; where c is constant tending towards 0, you can imagine c as infinitesimal. this is the functional relationship.

Comment: @Aatmaj: a variable constant, well done ! And what is $\dfrac{dc}{dt}$ ?

Comment: 0, c is infinitesimal, tending towards zero regardless value of t